# Поэлементное сравнение двумерного массива numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Итак, у меня есть 2 numpy матрицы, они отличаются только 1 элементом. Мне нужно, чтобы программа вычислила, сколько отличий между матрицами и вывела это.

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Как создать [mcve]?

Comment: Итак, мы за вас рады. Что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: Ну это ж элементарная задача, прям на начальные знания `numpy`